# Es6: Short version for destructuring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Is there a way to write the following code a bit shorter?

```
const { user } = JWT.verify(req.params.token, keys.secretOrKey);
const { email } = user;
```

I need just the `email` property from a JWT.

The data returned from `JWT.verify()` is an Object:

```
user: {
    name: 'the name',
    email: 'email@address.com',
    ...
}
```

Comment: Try `const { email } = JWT.verify(req.params.token, keys.secretOrKey).user;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destructuring assignment is quite powerful:

```js
// shim for example
const JWT = { verify: () => ({
  user: {
    email: 'me@me.me',
    name: 'snek',
  }, 
}) };

///////////////////

const { user: { email } } = JWT.verify();

console.log(email);
```

Note that `user` is not declared here.

See more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can just write

```
const {user:{email}} = JWT.verify(req.params.token, keys.secretOrKey);
```

```js
let test = { user: {
    name: 'the name',
    email: 'email@address.com'
    }}

const {user:{email}} = test;

console.log("user",typeof user);
console.log("email",email)
```

As you can see, only `email` is set, `user` is undefined.

Note though, that this will only work if `user` is defined, otherwise it will throw an error.

You can also set a default value for the `user` object, like so:

```js
let test = {/** user: {
    name: 'the name',
    email: 'email@address.com'
    }**/}

const {user:{email}={}} = test;

console.log("user",typeof user);
console.log("email",email)
```

So that it will not throw an error, if `user` isn't defined

Comment: Good note about the `user` having to be defined. Maybe it'd be good to point out how to default `user` to an empty object at the same time as a fail-safe?

Comment: Hey @chazsolo I hope that's what you meant, I haven't actually heard about this being possible, up until now ^^

Comment: Yep, exactly! You can also get `user` as an object at the same time: `const { user, user: { email } = {} } = test`.

Comment: Though that doesn't seem to be what the OP wants

Comment: No, just showing that destructuring isn't limited that way. What you have now is a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments:

```js
const myFunction = {
  user: {
    name: 'the name',
    email: 'email@address.com'
  }
}

const {
  email
} = myFunction.user

console.log(email)
```

Comment: Everyone went straight to more destructuring because of the title but this is _much_ easier to read (in my opinion). Nested destructuring is awkward and confusing.